# Config Self-Signed Cert to work with node,js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssl, self-signed

So I am currently working on a project that is looking to add SSL security to an web-app running on node.js that is being contained inside a Ubuntu core snap.

I am not a programmer so I am struggling to find a way to have the the app use the cert, let alone find a way to include it in the snap so that it will be part of the snap install process.

I understand that this might have to be separate processes but not having adequate footing to start from is making that hard to see.

Any direction in this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Snaps are containerised software packages that are simple to create and install, which are similar to apt, yum, dnf, pkg. I'm not sure how it is linked to running Node.js server on SSL. TO run node server on SSL, you need to create or have SSL certificates. You can do something like this:

```
var https = require('https');

var fs = require('fs');

var https_options = {

  key: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/private.key"),

  cert: fs.readFileSync("/path/to/your_domain_name.crt"),

  ca: [

          fs.readFileSync('path/to/CA_root.crt'),

          fs.readFileSync('path/to/ca_bundle_certificate.crt')

       ]
};
https.createServer(https_options, function (req, res) {

 res.writeHead(200);

 res.end("Welcome to Node.js HTTPS Servern");

}).listen(80)
```